# Combine Duplicate Items in a PSObject

Tags: powershell

I have several items inside a PowerShell object that are similar, I would like to combine them into a unique list based on 2 columns and the sum of the third column.

My Data Looks like this.[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEWy.png)

I want it to end up looking like this [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoL99.png)

here is my code when i create the object.  It's part of a foreach loop through a CSV.

```
$MSFTAdd = New-Object psobject -Property @{
"Client" = $MClientsubs.CustomerName
"SubscriptionName" = $MClientsubs.OfferName
"MicrosoftCount" = $MClientSubs.Quantity
}

$CustomMicrosoft += $MSFTAdd
}
```

Comment: the `Group-Object`  cmdlet can group by _more than one property_. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv is having sample data and below is the script to merge the duplicate rows

```
Import-Csv "testing.csv"|
Group-Object Client,SubscriptionName |
Select-Object @{Name='Client'   ;Expression={$_.Values[0]}},
              @{Name='SubscriptionName';Expression={$_.Values[1]}},
              @{Name='MicrosoftCount'  ;Expression={
                  ($_.Group|Measure-Object MicrosoftCount -Sum).Sum
                }}
              @{Name='MicrosoftAmount' ;Expression ={
                  ($_.Group|Measure-Object MicrosoftAmount -Sum).Sum)
              }} | Export-Csv ".\testing_new.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks,  how can i incorporate another column called "amount" that should also be summed?

Comment: Simply update your CSV file with a new column "MicrosoftAmount" followed by amounts/values. Just I have updated the above code with your requirements. Thanks!